# Coupling between the time() C function and the underlying hardware

Tags: c, gcc, mbed

This is more a general question. How is the coupling done between the `time()` c-function and the underlying hardware? Suppose that you compile for a microcontroller not containing any RTC, what value do you get back? Or if you use your own RTC that keeps running with battery on a separate chip? How do you update `time()` after repowering? Is there any method for redirecting?

I did a trial in Mbed with RTC and `time()` function with `MCU_STM32U575xG`.

See also https://forums.mbed.com/t/time-null-of-rtc-example-not-synchronizing-with-rtc-when-using-battery/22248/10

Comment: `time` doesn't have to be available in a freestanding environment

Comment: _" did a trial in Mbed with RTC and time() function" - And what was the result? Did you patch your environment with [this draft](https://github.com/mbed-ce/mbed-os/pull/210) that presumably fixes an issue if you call `time()` or `gettimeofday()` without calling `rtc_init()` first.

Comment: The result is that before the patch you had to do `rtc-init()` first to avoid that `gettimeofday()` was calling the time reset. Should be solved now. I now realize that you have to implement the time function by yourself, and that you only get the header from the lib. Probably the same with printf(), which is also hardware dependent.

Answer (score 0):

> How is the coupling done between the time() c-function and the underlying hardware?

There is no coupling "done". *You* have to "do it".

> what value do you get back?

I would expect a linking error, or maybe I would expect `time()` to return `(time_t)-1` with `errno` set to `ENOSYS`.

Returning -1 and ENOSYS is the default `nosys` implementation of `newlib` C standard library implementation so commonly used with GNU `arm-none-eabi-gcc` compiler toolchain here https://github.com/bminor/newlib/blob/master/libgloss/libnosys/gettod.c#L18 .

> I did a trial in Mbed with RTC and time() function with MCU_STM32U575xG.

In the case of mbed-os, time function is implemented here https://github.com/mbed-ce/mbed-os/blob/master/platform/source/mbed_rtc_time.cpp#L120 . The specifics of the function and what `_rtc_read()` function calls is configured with mbed-os configuration. *You* have to configure mbed-os and provide it with the configuration and compile with mbed-os.

Bottom line, there is no coupling. You have to make the coupling if you want it.

Comment: Ok I saw in case of mbed the coupling is done in a function. So you just get the 'format' in the C-lib and a header to include. Is it the same with `printf()` which is also a standard c-function and hardware dependent?

Comment: Hi, I do not understand the question. Everything is done by a function. The rest is unclear to me. It is the "same" with everything, or maybe it is different, it depends on how you look at it. There is no general answer. If you specifically use mbed then there exists a function inside mbed that does that. If you don't then it doesn't. If you use something, then there is somehing else. There are many many many implementations - newlib, keil, sdcc, zephyr, mbed, cmsis, and glibc, musl - and many architectures.

Comment: I meant that if you want to use printf/time that you always have to implement this function by yourself because it's hardware dependent. There is not such thing as if you compile for a specific target, that some magic happens behind the scene to make a coupling between stdlib and some predefined registers. The only reason to compile for a specific target is because of the translation to a specific instruction set.

Comment: But what if you compile a C program to run on a standard Linux/Windows machine? Do you also have to implement the printf and time functions by yourself? So where is the interfacing between the RTC chip, os and your own code?

Comment: `have to implement this function` Implement _that_ function, or a callback used by that function. In newlib you only implement `_write_r` to have console output `what if you compile a C program to run on a standard Linux/Windows` Then? It's the same, you either use a library or write it yourself, but usually use a library. On Linux, _typically_ it is glibc. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_standard_library#Implementations . Once again, there is no generic answer (except like on windows, it's MSVCRT). On specific linux you use specific tools, like on archlinux you would use glibc.

Comment: `where is the interfacing between the RTC chip` What exactly do you mean by "where"? There are layers upon layers. In transistors inside cpu? Cpu instructions? Memory cache lines? Hardware registers? Memory addresses? Exact DMA addresses? PCI buses? Source code? Typically, Linux kernel has an RTC driver, which exposes an user space interface, which systemd-timedated reads. Or it doesn't, and the driver is implemented in user-space. Or there is no systemd. It depends on the specific system. https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/rtc.html  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel_interfaces

Comment: Bottom line, from a close up perspective, it is just very very fragmented. For _typical_ RTC on a X86 typical PC motherboard, you might be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACPI , https://uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/ACPI_6_2.pdf around section 9.18 . This is _not_ anyhow related to STM32, which does not "support" ACPI in any fashion. There are https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/rtc so many RTC drivers in linux kernel with https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/rtc/rtc-cmos.c looks like the main one.